# Android keyboard with keystroke memory?

Tags: android, keyboard, keylogger

Just as that. I want to have access to all my keystrokes typed anytime in the past. And I don't want to install a separate keylogger app for that. Let's call it keyboard with a built-in keylogger, ideally with the clipboard history  support. Are there such apps? Quick search gave nothing for me.

Comment: Googling "android keyboard memory keystroke app" returned [LokiBoard - Android Keylogger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abifog.lokiboard). I haven't tried it, but the reviews said that it's working as claimed. Not sure about clipboard history though.

Comment: thx, will try it